# Java - Upload images to website with user form input, save them in MySQL databse, and display image on website

Tags: java, mysql, image, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Sorry if I say something or ask something silly here. I am still very new to programming.

I am creating a website where users can create events and add basic information like a title, description, contact email, and dates/times of the event.

In addition to all of that information, I want to add an upload photo feature so users can upload an image to accompany it. When users use the website, they can view other events created by other users with all the information and an image. I would say it is pretty similar to Facebook Events.

However, I am stuck trying to figure out how to incorporate it into my code or where to even start. I have watched and read many videos and articles on image uploading and a lot of them use Php and PHPMyAdmin. I've never worked with Php before, and I have been writing my program in Java. I have a small idea of what the HTML portion will look like but I have no idea how to start with the code I have so far and I am not understanding how to save it in my MySQl database.

This is my Events.java class:

```
@Entity
public class Events extends AbstractEntity {

    @NotBlank(message = "Name field cannot be left blank.")
    @Size(min = 2, max = 50, message = "Name must be between 2 and 50 characters")
    private String eventName;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Valid
    @NotNull
    private EventDetails eventDetails;

    public Event(@NotBlank(message = "Name field cannot be left blank.") @Size(min = 2, max = 50, message = "Name must be between 2 and 50 characters") String eventName) {
        this.eventName = eventName;
    }

    public Event(){}

    public String getEventName() {
        return eventName;
    }

    public void setEventName(String eventName) {
        this.eventName = eventName;
    }

    public EventDetails getEventDetails() {
        return eventDetails;
    }

    public void setEventDetails(EventDetails eventDetails) {
        this.eventDetails = eventDetails;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return eventName;
    }
}
```

This is my create.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org/">
<head th:replace="fragments :: head"></head>
<head>
    <link th:href="@{/css/events.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body class="create-events-body">
    <header th:replace="fragments :: header"></header>
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <nav>
                <ul class="event-nav">
                    <li><a href="/events" class="all-cta">All Events</a>
                        <a href="/events/create" class="primary-cta">Create an Event</a>
                        <a href="/evetns/delete" class="secondary-cta">Delete an Event</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>

    <section class="create-events-section">
        <form method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-wrapper">
                    <div>
                        <label class="form-name">Event Name:
                            <input th:field="${event.eventName}" class="form-control">
                        </label>
                        <p class="error" th:errors="${event.eventName}"></p>
                        <label class="form-email">Contact Email:
                            <input th:field="${event.eventDetails.eventContactEmail}" class="form-control">
                        </label>
                        <p class="error" th:errors="${event.eventDetails.eventContactEmail}"></p>
                        <label class="form-description">Description:
                            <textarea th:field="${event.eventDetails.eventDescription}" class="form-control"></textarea>
                        </label>
                        <p class="error" th:errors="${event.eventDetails.eventDescription}"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Create Event">
            </div>
        </form>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try XAMPP for testing your own MySQL database on your own computer trough PHPMyAdmin.
Use secure password for XAMPP.
Use MySQL libraries for Java coding (for example, if You code in NetBeans).
Search for command lines how to work with MySQL trough java code.
Learn syntax of PHP.
Search for some good PHP free editing software and edit code as you need.